# while using a intellij on remote linux server on window(Xshell client), I came across an error that intellij crashes all of a sudden

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, xshell

I am a student working on a lab in university.
while trying to start intellij on Linux through Xshell, I encountered an error that intellij crashes. My intellij version is 2023.1 and I am using intellij Ultimate version.
how can I handle this? please help me.

```
typeroot@leegang-DREAMSYS:/home/leegang/labnote# intellij-idea-ultimate 
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
2023-09-07 21:14:54,838 [   2531]   WARN - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Duplicated scheme Light - old: Light, new Light
2023-09-07 21:15:14,298 [  21991]   WARN - #o.j.i.maven - updateAllMavenProjectsSync started, edt=false
2023-09-07 21:15:15,878 [  23571]   WARN - #o.j.i.maven - updateAllMavenProjectsSync finished, edt=false
Info  | RdCoroutineScope          | 56:DefaultDispatcher-worker-40 | RdCoroutineHost overridden 
2023-09-07 21:15:19,161 [  26854]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.i.ActionUpdater - 346 ms to grab EDT for LiveEditIssueNotificationAction#update@EditorInspectionsToolbar (com.android.tools.idea.editors.liveedit.ui.LiveEditIssueNotificationAction)
2023-09-07 21:15:20,670 [  28363]   WARN - #c.i.e.r.RemoteProcessSupport - SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
2023-09-07 21:15:20,671 [  28364]   WARN - #c.i.e.r.RemoteProcessSupport - SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/449/plugins/maven/lib/maven36-server.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
2023-09-07 21:15:20,678 [  28371]   WARN - #c.i.e.r.RemoteProcessSupport - SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/449/lib/util-8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
2023-09-07 21:15:20,678 [  28371]   WARN - #c.i.e.r.RemoteProcessSupport - SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
2023-09-07 21:15:20,678 [  28371]   WARN - #c.i.e.r.RemoteProcessSupport - SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3WrapperSl4LoggerFactory]
2023-09-07 21:15:20,843 [  28536]   WARN - #c.i.i.s.p.i.BundledSharedIndexPostStartupActivity - Skipped 1 pre-built shared indexes: bundled-js-predefined-1d06a55b98c1-8314e18161f9-JavaScript-IU-232.9559.62
2023-09-07 21:15:20,888 [  28581]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.i.ActionUpdater - 344 ms to grab EDT for LiveEditIssueNotificationAction#update@EditorInspectionsToolbar (com.android.tools.idea.editors.liveedit.ui.LiveEditIssueNotificationAction)
 here
```

I removed intellij and re-installed. But it's not still working.

Comment: Try resolution steps from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559-Start-Failed-Internal-error-recovering-IDE-to-the-working-state-after-the-critical-startup-error If the problem remains, contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: No error shown btw. That's a *warning*, probably from an app, about logging. If something crashes, how about other gui apps on the same server using the same client?